# SignalR Client performance issues

Tags: reactjs, performance, signalr

Dose anyone know if there is rule of the thumb which hardware is required for an client with an react application this should process around 30 SignalR messages a second?

I have a client application which sometimes looks like it has high latency to display the changed value. I am aware this could also be related to some bad implementation in react key word "to many re-render".

On my developer machine this behavior didn't occurred yet.

Are there some tips about tooling or how to monitor the application to discover the problem?

Thanks!